# How can I call gdal_translate from Java code?

Tags: gdal, java

How can I execute `gdal_translate` in Java? For example, will something like this work?

```
gdal_translate "PG:host=localhost dbname='xyzy' schema=public' table='xyz'" "d:\xyx\ab.tiff"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the quotes and gdal_translate expression

```
// Execute command
String gdal_translate="gdal_translate "+"PG:host=localhost dbname='xyzy'                      schema=public' table='xyz'"+"d:\xyx\ab.tiff"";
String command0 = "cmd /c start /min /wait "+gdal_translate;
Process child0 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command0);
child0.waitFor();
```